# Why does this clipboard manipulation that works on Vim not work on GVIM?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, terminal, os-clipboard

In my `.vimrc` I have this piece of code:

```
" Gist it to bl.ocks.org {{{
let g:gist_clip_command = 'xclip -selection clipboard'
command! -range=% Blocks
    \ <line1>,<line2>Format format | f index.html | exe 'Gist! -p' | bd!                                    |
    \ let @+ = 'http://bl.ocks.org/oblitum/raw/' . matchstr(@+, 'https://gist.github.com/\zs\w\+\ze') . '/' |
    \ let @+ = bitly#shorten(@+).url | redraw | echomsg 'Done: ' . @+ | setlocal nomodified
" }}}
```

[Source](https://github.com/oblitum/dotfiles/blob/86e15d31503649af6c24caba396a71158f5423a9/.vimrc#L708-L714)

At the top of the `.vimrc` I set `clipboard=unnamedplus` and add all the necessary plugins (frawor, formatvim, webapi-vim, gist-vim, bitly.vim). This command is to get buffer contents including highlighting and post it to a web page online.

This command works when executed from Vim in the terminal, but it doesn't when executed from GVIM.

On GVIM it seems that `Gist! -p` works for saving the gist url into the clipboard but then all the remaining command parts that are supposed to edit and transform this content in the clipboard seems to be doing nothing and in the end the `echomsg` just displays what was created by the original `Gist! -p`.

Answer (score 1):

`let g:gist_clip_command = 'xclip -selection clipboard'` configuration is not necessary on GVIM and it's the culprit.

Comment: You can wrap it in `if !has('gui_running')` to run it only for terminal Vim.